# Where is Button.DialogResult in WPF?

Tags: wpf, button, dialogresult

In [System.Windows.**Forms**.Button](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.button.aspx) there is a property [DialogResult](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.button.dialogresult.aspx), where is this property in the [System.Windows.**Controls**.Button](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.button.aspx) (WPF)?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

There is no built-in Button.DialogResult, but you can create your own (if you like) using a simple attached property:

```
public class ButtonHelper
{
  // Boilerplate code to register attached property "bool? DialogResult"
  public static bool? GetDialogResult(DependencyObject obj) { return (bool?)obj.GetValue(DialogResultProperty); }
  public static void SetDialogResult(DependencyObject obj, bool? value) { obj.SetValue(DialogResultProperty, value); }
  public static readonly DependencyProperty DialogResultProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("DialogResult", typeof(bool?), typeof(ButtonHelper), new UIPropertyMetadata
  {
    PropertyChangedCallback = (obj, e) =>
    {
      // Implementation of DialogResult functionality
      Button button = obj as Button;
      if(button==null)
          throw new InvalidOperationException(
            "Can only use ButtonHelper.DialogResult on a Button control");
      button.Click += (sender, e2) =>
      {
        Window.GetWindow(button).DialogResult = GetDialogResult(button);
      };
    }
  });
}
```

This will allow you to write:

```
<Button Content="Click Me" my:ButtonHelper.DialogResult="True" />
```

and get behavior equivalent to WinForms (clicking on the button causes the dialog to close and return the specified result)

Comment: I learned new stuff in herer, this attatching, eventho im not going to use it in this case, sure will be useful! thanks a lot

Comment: I never knew about the GetWindow func, that's just amazing!

Comment: A great solution, made greater in its simplicity.

Answer (score 24):

There is no `Button.DialogResult` in WPF. You just have to set the `DialogResult` of the `Window` to true or false :

```
private void buttonOK_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    this.DialogResult = true;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just make sure that you've shown the form using `ShowDialog` rather than `Show`. If you do the latter you'll get the following exception raised:

> InvalidOperationException was unhandled
>
> DialogResult can be set only after Window is created and shown as dialog.

Answer (score -5):

```
MessageBoxResult result = MessageBox.Show("","");

if (result == MessageBoxResult.Yes)
{
// CODE IN HERE
}
else 
{
// CODE IN HERE
}
```

Comment: This code won't even work... `MessageBox.Show("", "");` will not show Yes|No buttons.