# Progress Bar without Windows Button

Tags: c#, wpf

I have an application which takes time to load so i would like to display a progress bar in a small window such that it should not have any buttons like minimize,maximize and close button the progress bar should be standalone. Is there any way to display progress bar without any buttons.

Comment: To hide the close button see:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/743906/how-to-hide-close-button-in-wpf-window

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, just set the [`WindowStyle`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.windowstyle.aspx) to `None`, and possibly [`ResizeMode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.resizemode.aspx) to `NoResize`.

Answer (score 1):

place the progress bar control in the window control and in xaml set these properties with your window tag

```
<Window x:Class="XXX"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Height="20" Width="50" WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen" 
        WindowStyle="None"
        ResizeMode="NoResize"
        ShowInTaskbar="False" >
```