# WPF Window ornament nomenclature

Tags: wpf, nomenclature

Winforms can switch the ControlBox, Maximize and Minimize buttons on and off. I can't seem to find the equivalent properties to control the window ornaments in WPF. What's the correct nomenclature so I can look up this stuff in msdn?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change this by setting the `ResizeMode` of the window

EG:

```
ResizeMode="NoResize" 
or
WindowStyle="ToolWindow"
```

will show no minimize/maximize buttons

Comment: I'm already using that but it leaves the ControlBox and the Close button.

Comment: As far as I can tell, the only way is to completely replace the ControlTemplate.

Comment: If yo want nothing at all you can use `WindowStyle="None"`, however this will remove the top border totally, so the only way to do it without that happining is using P-Invoke to remove the close button, this thread may be a good place to start, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/743906/how-to-hide-close-button-in-wpf-window

Comment: I tell a lie, ToolWindow does hide the controlbox. I don't really want to use PInvoke to mess with basic window behaviour and I'm too lazy to write a whole control template, so I'm going with the ToolWindow suggestion, with a handler on closing to hide instead.