# C# WPF Disable the exit/close button

Tags: c#, wpf

Is it possible to disable the close button in a WPF form?
How can I disable the close button?

I have been searching around and found the solution below. But that works only in Windows Form!

```
private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
      e.Cancel = true;
}
```

Comment: look at this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/743906/how-to-hide-close-button-in-wpf-window

Answer (score 18, accepted):

in wpf this event called Closing :

```
public Window4()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.Closing += new System.ComponentModel.CancelEventHandler(Window4_Closing);
    }

    void Window4_Closing(object sender, System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Cancel = true;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to implement a windows hook to accomplish that. See [this MSDN post](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/wpf/thread/549a4bbb-e77b-4c5a-b724-07996774c60a/) for details.