# How to hide the close button in a MahApps.Metro window?

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, xaml, mahapps.metro

I'm trying to hide/remove the close button on my MahApps MetroWindow without success.

I've tried with this code:

```
private const int GWL_STYLE = -16;
private const int WS_SYSMENU = 0x80000;
[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
private static extern int GetWindowLong(IntPtr hWnd, int nIndex);
[DllImport("user32.dll")]

private static extern int SetWindowLong(IntPtr hWnd, int nIndex, int dwNewLong);

private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
        var hwnd = new WindowInteropHelper(this).Handle;
        SetWindowLong(hwnd, GWL_STYLE, GetWindowLong(hwnd, GWL_STYLE) & ~WS_SYSMENU);
}
```

I've also set up some properties:

```
...ShowTitleBar="False" WindowStyle="None" ResizeMode="NoResize" 
    Loaded="Window_Loaded" ...
```

So the Window_Loaded is trigger correctly but the code of this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/743906/how-to-hide-close-button-in-wpf-window) seems not working.

This is the actual result:

[image]

Why the button don't disappear? What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: It works just fine when I try it.  But this does not look like a normal Window class, hard to guess where ShowTitleBar comes from.

Comment: I'm using mahapp metro framework, maybe this is the problem?

Comment: Yes, that's the problem.  Clearly you need to update your question.

Comment: Uhm well, I honestly do not know who provide more details. I asked about git support mahapp to take a look at this question, maybe their can deal with the problem.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can use the `ShowCloseButton` dependency property of the `MetroWindow`.

Comment: Thanks, your toolkit is awesome dude.