# Hide one desktop window or disable closing button - Windows Desktop App

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, desktop-application

I am creating a Windows Desktop App to run on Windows 8.1 Pro.

Programmatically I can minimize it using this property:

```
WindowState.Minimized;
```

Is there a way to hide it completely instead, or disable the user to close it?

I tried with all [these StackOverflow solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/743906/how-to-hide-close-button-in-wpf-window) but

they dont work to me.

I tried with

```
private const int GWL_STYLE = -16;
private const int WS_SYSMENU = 0x80000;
[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
private static extern int GetWindowLong(IntPtr hWnd, int nIndex);
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
private static extern int SetWindowLong(IntPtr hWnd, int nIndex, int dwNewLong);
```

and

```
var hwnd = new WindowInteropHelper(this).Handle;
SetWindowLong(hwnd, GWL_STYLE, GetWindowLong(hwnd, GWL_STYLE) & ~WS_SYSMENU);
```

then I tried with adding the below method to my windows class

```
protected override void OnClosing(CancelEventArgs e)
{
   base.OnClosing(e);
   e.Cancel = true;
}
```

the I tried with this property

```
        WindowStyle = WindowStyle.None;
```

still with no luck.

How can I get it?

I am using VS2015 and WPF

Comment: Use `<Window ...  WindowStyle="None">` in XAML. Add your own buttons.

Comment: already tried but it does not work

Comment: Can't be, i do it few times, always work fine. M.b. you have some another logic to window that disable it at runtime. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.windowstyle(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply set the `ShowInTaskBar` property  to `False` in your xaml-

```
ShowInTaskbar="False"
```

and in the c# code, just hide your window on the program initialization:

```
  public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.Hide();
    }
```

Goodluck.

Comment: what is this supposed to do?

Comment: it does not change anything

Comment: @eeadev what do you mean does not change anything?