# How to hide close button and disable resizing in WPF window?

Tags: c#, wpf, pinvoke, setwindowlong

I'm writing a wpf window which have a custom minmize button and close button instead of the default one, at mean while it should not be resizable. Simply set `WindowStyle=None` and `ResizeMode=NoResize` did work, but I hope other default window behaviors retained as well (such as shadows, animations, corner radius etc..)

After many search I found [this P/Invoke method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/958980/3458665),

```
private const int GWL_STYLE = -16;
private const int WS_SYSMENU = 0x80000;
[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
private static extern int GetWindowLong(IntPtr hWnd, int nIndex);
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
private static extern int SetWindowLong(IntPtr hWnd, int nIndex, int dwNewLong);
```

then

```
var hwnd = new WindowInteropHelper(this).Handle;
SetWindowLong(hwnd, GWL_STYLE, GetWindowLong(hwnd, GWL_STYLE) & ~WS_SYSMENU);
```

It works fine for me, and use code below could just disable window resizing.

```
private const int WS_SIZEBOX = 0x00040000;
SetWindowLong(hwnd, GWL_STYLE, GetWindowLong(hwnd, GWL_STYLE) & ~WS_SIZEBOX);
```

Now the problem is that `~WS_SYSMENU` and `~WS_SIZEBOX` could not valid at the same time. Once I set `~WS_SYSMENU`, the window is resizable whether ever `~WS_SIZEBOX` is set. Could anyone help me? Any advices are grateful.

Forgot to mention that I did set them together as a bro just commented:

```
SetWindowLong(hwnd, GWL_STYLE, GetWindowLong(hwnd, GWL_STYLE) & ~(WS_SIZEBOX | WS_SYSMENU));
```

Comment: When I did so, I got a window that cannot be resized, on Win10. Have you checked the return value of SetWindowLong?

Comment: I checked the return value of `GetWindowLong(hwnd, GWL_STYLE) & ~(WS_SIZEBOX | WS_SYSMENU)`, it was something like 0x06c20000 in my case, on Win11. The 18th and 19th bit was set to zero, which is as expected. Did you got a window cannot be resized and without close button as well? I will check the return value of SetWindowLong, thank you!

Comment: The return value of `GetWindowLong(hwnd, GWL_STYLE) & ~(WS_SIZEBOX | WS_SYSMENU)` was 0x06c20000, but the return value of SetWindowLong was 0x06ca0000, It's weird. In what case this would happen? @shingo

Comment: Yes, no close button. Your return value of SetWindowLong is okay. But on my system the style is 0x16C30000, so your window is invisible at the beginning?

Comment: I tried to directly set the style to 0x16C30000, `SetWindowLong(hwnd, GWL_STYLE, 0x16C30000`, still the same issue. Maybe something is different on Win11.

Comment: I created a new demo window with nothing but a label, then `SetWindowLong(hwnd, GWL_STYLE, 0x16C30000)`, then I got a window as expected. I guess some other factors may affect the window behavior, I will check it further. Thank you very much! @shingo

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found out that was a `WindowChrome` issue. In my xaml code have codes like:

```
<WindowChrome.WindowChrome>
    <WindowChrome GlassFrameThickness="-1" CaptionHeight="0"/>
</WindowChrome.WindowChrome>
```

After set the `ResizeBorderThickness` property to zero the issue resolved.

```
<WindowChrome GlassFrameThickness="-1" CaptionHeight="0" ResizeBorderThickness="0"/>
```